# Vulnerability Scans Against Newly Launched EC2

Tags: security, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I launched an EC2 instance a few days ago, it's launched from an ECS service. It's only being used by me and a couple of others for testing purposes. It hosts an API that an iOS app connects to. Almost immediately in the logs I started seeing and continue to see vulnerability scans against it similar to the below.

2020-07-14T08:27:37.031+01:00
[0;36m[ INFO ][0m ERROR From: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX, Description: GET / HTTP/1.1

Host: X.X.XXX.XX

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 zgrab/0.x

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip

The scans are against the IP rather than the DNS and a series of scans are run every few hours. This is the first time I've run an EC2 for any period of time, always used Heroku before now which either hid these things from me or never encountered them. Is this just them scanning entire IP address ranges and finding my service or do I have a leak somewhere that's alerting them to the launch of the service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet is being scanned by the crawlers and scanners all the time. Hard to tell whether the purpose is malicious or not. The one scanning you is the zgrab tool you can find here: https://zmap.io/.

Comment: Thanks Marek. Makes sense for scans of root. Would a benign scanner look for routes like: 404: GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php Not Found?

Comment: Looks like someone is scanning the servers to hack into: https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2017-9841

Comment: Thought it might be the case. There are many other scans looking for phpadmin login pages and the like. Is this typical activity on a newly launched server? Is there that much active opportunistic vulnerability scanning going on?

Comment: I believe there may be many willing to join your EC2 instance into their bitcoin mining cluster. :)